# Custom output folder on TFS build server

Tags: msbuild, build-process, azure-devops

Im having trouble setting up my build to work correctly on a TFS build server (Visual Studio Online).
I have a collection of projects that build in to a custom directory structure. This works flawless when building locally.
Structure is:

```
.
+---Binaries
|   +---Application
|   +---Client
|   +---Common
|   +---Server
+---Development
|   +---ClientProj
|   +---Databaseproj
|   +---ProjN
```

The output of each project is set to `..\..\Binaries\Application\` etc.
Im using one solution to build each subproject.
Can anyone guide me to get this to work on my build server also?

Answer (score 0):

The best thing is to change the folders back to the default and have the folders post built for you. There is a nuget package called _PublishedAplication that, when added to the project, creates a _PublishedApplication[applicationName] folder in the drop output for each app..